# gwtp app doesn't work in jboss or tomcat

Tags: gwt, tomcat, jboss, gwt-platform

I compiled my gwtp app, and tried to run in jboss, and it throwed this:

> SEVERE: Cookie provided by RPC doesn't match request cookie, aborting
>   action, possible XSRF attack. (Maybe you forgot to set the security
>   cookie?) While executing action:
>   hu.irf.portal.ui.shared.fnc.torzs.GetOrgList
>   2012.02.13. 16:55:30 com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.AbstractDispatchServiceImpl
>   cookieMatch INFO: No cookie sent by client in RPC. (Did you forget to
>   bind the security cookie client-side? Or it could be an attack.)

It worked fine in development mode.

I tried to set the `useHttpOnly` parameter to false in the tomcat's `context.xml`, but it is also not working.

Comment: `INFO: No cookie sent by client in RPC.` -- Are you sending a cookie? If not, are you expecting one on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Your `context.xml` should look like:

```
<Context useHttpOnly="false">
    ...
</Context>
```

To make sure there is nothing overriding this setting, place `context.xml` in your WAR's `/META-INF` directory.  *That is the `META-INF` directory off of root, not `/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF`*  See [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) for more on defining your context

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to clear cache of your browser. Use FireCookie in Firefox to see if your cookie was sent.